# Qlik - How to use Set Analysis to sum until the last available record with data instead of the last calendar date

Tags: calendar, qlikview, qliksense

**My expression looks currently like this:**

```
Sum({$<[Calendar Date] = {
<=$(=Date(MonthEnd(Date(Today()))))
>=$(=Date(AddMonths(MonthStart(Date(Today())), - 12)))"}>} [Amount])
```

**This is how the data looks like:**

```
Companies   MonthYear   Amount
Company1    201701  10000
Company1    201612  20000
Company2    201701  -
Company2    201612  -
Company2    201611  35000
Company2    201610  17000
Company3    201701  -
Company3    201612  50000
Company3    201611  10000
Company3    201610  24000
Company3    201609  40000
Company3    201608  -
Company3    201607  -
Company3    201606  32000
Company3    201605  18000
```

**This is what I want to achieve:**

Example:

- Company1 has data until 201701 --> sum data from 201601 until 201701
- Company2 has data until 201611 --> sum data from 201511 until 201611
- Company3 has data until 201612 --> sum data from 201512 until 201612

**But because I am using Today() as my limit I am having the following displayed: (THIS IS NOT WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE)**

Example:

- Company1 has data until 201701 --> sum data from 201601 until 201701
- Company2 has data until 201611 --> sum data from 201601 until 201701
- Company3 has data until 201612 --> sum data from 201601 until 201701

How do I need to change the expression so that my dashboard will sum the [Amount] field from the last available month with data for every company until the 12 months before that date?

**PS:** Today() = 23 Jan 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what expression I have to use:

**I just had to replace Today() with the maximum month where amount was available**

```
Sum({$< [Calendar Date] = {"
<=$(=Date(MonthEnd(Date(Date(MonthEnd(Date(Max(Aggr(Max({$<[Calendar Date] = 
{"<=$(=Date(MonthEnd(Date(Today()))))"}, [Amount] = {"<>0"}>}
[Calendar Date]), [Companies])))))))))
>=$(=Date(AddMonths(MonthStart(Date(Date(MonthEnd(Date(Max(
Aggr(Max({$<[Calendar Date] = {"<=$(=Date(MonthEnd(Date(Today()))))"}, [Amount] = {"<>0"}>}
[Calendar Date]), [Companies]))))))), -12)))"}>} [Amount])
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work...

```
=Sum({<MonthYear={'$(=Max(MonthYear))'}>}Amount)
```

Comment: Thanks but this will only display the amount of the maximum month for a particular company, this is not enough. I am trying to get a range: *Last month with data available for a particular company* --> *12 months before that month*. If you look at my expression, I need to find a way to replace Today() by a variable which detects the last month with data available for every company.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've answered your own question, but want to offer another suggestion.

If you're looking to aggregate values over time periods (i.e. the last year), and you'll only ever want to look at the last year, you could reduce complexity of that set analysis by putting some flags into your data model. I know it's not set analysis, but it will improve the performance of your UI if it scales out, as you're using a number of complex functions to achieve something we can do simply in the model.

This load script does three things:

1. Loads your data (I had to format the date so QV would recognise it)
2. Gets the latest date with amounts in for each company
3. Iterates to create a list of the last 12 months, and joins this back to the original table as a flag field (Flag_LatestYear)

Then, in your set analysis you can use the following expression in your charts (where they have the "companies" field as a dimension).

```
Sum({$<Flag_LatestYear={1}>}Amount)
```

Here's a comparison of what the amount field will normally sum, and with the set analysis (which removes an additional record which I added - that's deliberately out of range)

[Normal Sum vs Set Analysis for the latest 12 months available for each company](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y6cQ.png)

Here's the load script.

```
// Load raw data - preceding load used to clean up date. I added a new row at the bottom that was deliberately out of the date range it should pick up
OriginalTable:
LOAD
    Companies,
    DATE(DATE#([Calendar Date],'YYYYMM')) AS [Calendar Date],
    Amount;
LOAD * INLINE [
    Companies,   Calendar Date,   Amount
    Company1,    201701,  10000
    Company1,    201612,  20000
    Company2,    201701,  -
    Company2,    201612,  -
    Company2,    201611,  35000
    Company2,    201610,  17000
    Company3,    201701,  -
    Company3,    201612,  50000
    Company3,    201611,  10000
    Company3,    201610,  24000
    Company3,    201609,  40000
    Company3,    201608,  -
    Company3,    201607,  -
    Company3,    201606,  32000
    Company3,    201605,  18000
    Company3,    201405,  50000
];


// Grab the max dates from the loaded table
TEMP_MaxDate:
LOAD
    Companies,
    MAX([Calendar Date]) AS CalendarDateMax
RESIDENT OriginalTable
WHERE Amount > 0
GROUP BY Companies;

// This is a cheat, but I've put it in as your dataset is small. It'll iterate through and create joining records for every month in the last 12, per company
// I'll use this to join back to the OriginalTable for my flag. Note that it joins on two fields - a key would be better
LEFT JOIN (OriginalTable)
LOAD
    Companies,
    DATE(AddMonths(CalendarDateMax,-iterNo() + 1)) AS [Calendar Date],
    1 AS Flag_LatestYear
RESIDENT TEMP_MaxDate
WHILE AddYears(CalendarDateMax,-1) <= AddMonths(CalendarDateMax,-iterNo() + 1);

// Clean up and remove the temp table
DROP TABLE TEMP_MaxDate;
```

As always there will be other ways of achieving this! Let me know if this was helpful.